# Legal change to JSON input invalidates simple jq

Tags: json, jq

Another department continually updates a JSON file that I then query.  Its format is three lists of similar-looking dictionaries:

```
{
"levels":
[
{"a":1, "b":False, "c":"2012", "d":"2017"}
,{"a":2, "b":True,  "c":"2013", "d":"9999"}
,...
]
,"costs":
[
{"e":12, "f":"foo", "g":"blarg", "h":"2015", "i":"2018"}
,{"e":-3, "f":"foo", "g":"glorb", "h":"2013", "i":"9999"}
,...
]
,"recipes":
[
{"j":"BAZ", "k":["blarg","glorb","bleeg"], "l":"dill", "m":"2016", "n":"2017"}
,{"j":"BAZ", "k":["blarg","bleeg"], "l":"dill", "m":"2017", "n":"9999"}
,...
]
}   # line 3943 (see below)
```

Recently, my simple `jq` queries like

```
jq '.["recipes"][] | select(.l | test("ill"))' < jsonfile
```

stopped returning all of the results they should (e.g. returning only one of the two "dill" lines above) and started printing this error message:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:3943): null (null) cannot be matched, as it is not a string
```

Line 3943 mentioned in the error is the final line of the file.  Queries against the "levels" and "costs" sections of the file continue to work like normal; it's only the "recipes" section of the file that is breaking, as though `jq` thinks the closing brace of the file is still part of the "recipes" section.

To me this suggests there's been a formatting change or error in the last section of the file.  However, software other than `jq` (e.g. `python`) doesn't report any problems parsing it.  Before I start going through the input line by line ... does this error message indicate anything obvious to a `jq` expert?

Alas, I do not keep old versions of the file around for comparison.  (I think I will start today.)

Answer (score -1):

(self-answering after a bit of investigating)

I think there was no formatting error or change in formatting in the input.

I don't know why my query syntax did **not** encounter errors previously (maybe I just did not notice), but it seems that the entries in the "recipes" section often do not contain an "l" attribute, and `jq` will cease processing as soon as it encounters one that does not.

I also don't know why `jq` does not generate the same error message for **every** record that lacks that attribute, nor why it waits to the final line of the input to generate the single message.  (Maybe that behavior is documented somewhere.)

In any case, I fixed the error (not just the message, but also the failure to display all relevent records) by testing for the presence of the attribute first:

```
jq '.["recipes"][] | select(has("l") and (.l | test("ill")))' < jsonfile
```

Comment: If an object has no "l" key, then `.l` will evaluate to `null`, and then `test("ill")` will raise an error.  Once an error has been raised, jq will exit unless the error is caught.